# How do I set two cookies with the same name?

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-4

When I try to do this:

```
Cookie::queue('somename', $val, 300, '/', 'main.example.com')
Cookie::queue('somename', $val, 300, '/', 'other.example.com')
```

Only one of the cookies gets set, because the queue function is setting `queued[$cookie->getName()]` to the cookie, and they both have the same name. Is there any way I can queue two cookies with the same name?

Comment: no cookies can not have same name.. if u do then the last one will be updated with the new one.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Of course he can have such cookies - look at the domains. The question is how to set them in L4